# What did the Weasleys do during the first war with Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any information about what Ron's parents were up to the first time Voldemort was running amuck?

I don't recall hearing about them being in the Order of the Phoenix the first time around, but it seems strange that they would have simply sat on the side lines.

Comment: I *think* this is covered briefly in *Order of the Phoenix*, but I can't say definitely. I'll see if I can find a quote from the book.

Comment: Weren't they too young for that?

Comment: They would have been close to the age of Harry's parents.   They seem to be a little bit older than Sirius and Lupen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No quotes off the top of my head (I didn't find anything from JKR either), but Molly wasn't in the order since she was raising the older Weasley kids (all the boys were born **during** the war). I don't think it's specified whether Arthur was in the Order (Wikia says he wasn't, but there's no actual evidence for or against - he wasn't in the original Order photograph, though).

Comment: The older Weasley children were older than Harry, but Lily was still part of the Order.

Answer (score 0):

Molly was born in 1949 and Arthur in 1950 and attend school in 1961-1968, so 10 (?) years older then Harry's parents who were born in 1960s. Bill was born in 1970.

Comment: Did JKR mention this somewhere, or did you just calculate it out? :)

Answer (score 0):

#### The Weasleys got married during the last war.

Arthur and Molly got married during Voldemort’s last rise to power, and Molly had several children while the war was ongoing.

> “I know why it’s happened, of course. It’s all this uncertainty with You-Know-Who coming back, people think they might be dead tomorrow, so they’re rushing all sorts of decisions they’d normally take time over. It was the same last time he was powerful, people eloping left right and centre –’
>
> ‘Including you and Dad,’ said Ginny slyly.
>
> ‘Yes, well, your father and I were made for each other, what was the point in waiting?’ said Mrs Weasley.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 5 (An Excess of Phlegm)*</sup></sub>

The majority, if not all, of their children would have been born during the war as well, since Harry was a bit over one year old when the war ended and Ginny is about one year younger than him.

#### Molly Weasley was not in the Order then.

It’s never specified whether Arthur Weasley was in the original Order of the Phoenix, though he is not in the photograph of the original Order. However, it is confirmed that Molly was not in the original Order.

> “Oh, Molly, come on, it’s about time you got used to hearing his name – look, I can’t promise no one’s going to get hurt, nobody can promise that, but we’re much better off than we were last time. You weren’t in the Order then, you don’t understand.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 9 (The Woes of Mrs Weasley)*</sup></sub>

So it’s relatively likely but not confirmed that Arthur wasn’t in the Order, and explicitly stated that Molly wasn’t in the Order.